# Depth First Search, my code cant find the path

Tags: prolog, depth-first-search

I tried this code for depth first search in Prolog, but it is not complete. It did not show the path. 
This is my tree and Roles for depth first search:

```
mov(a,b).
mov(a,f).
mov(a,c).
mov(a,d).
mov(b,e).
mov(b,f).
mov(e,h).
mov(e,i).
mov(f,j).
mov(f,g).
mov(c,g).

dfs([],[],_):- !.
dfs([H],NL,G):- H=G, !, append(NL,G,L).
dfs([H|T],C,G):- mov(H,N1), append(C,H,NL), dfs([N1],NL,G).
```

Comment: Prolog recurses depth first. You don't need `append`. What is `L` in your second predicate clause for `dfs`? And please show an example query.

Comment: It's unclear what `dfs` is supposed to do. I understand generally it's to do a depth-first search, but what is it intended to accomplish? Show example query with inputs/outputs. Your use of `append` has problems, as the second argument you have is a list element, but `append` is intended to operate on lists. But as I mentioned before, `append` is unnecessary here.

Comment: i know we do not need append, but my teacher said you have to add unwanted Roots to A list with name Close, i used append to add to close list.
query : dfs([a],C,g)  %the g is the Goal.
sorry if i have mistakes in my English speak.